# (SQL) Struggling with using sum

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sum

I'm learning SQL, and struggling with some of the syntax. So, the following SQL code is supposed to display a list of suppliers and the total price of all of their products. It works fine until I try to include the extra condition where I only want it to display the rows where the total sum is less than 100.

```
SELECT Suppliers.SupplierName, SUM(Products.Price)
FROM Suppliers, Products
WHERE Suppliers.SupplierID = Products.SupplierID
AND Products.Price < 100
GROUP BY Suppliers.SupplierName;
```

As the code is at the moment, it simply omits individual values larger than 100 from the final total. Changing the code to

```
AND SUM(Products.Price) < 100
```

didn't work either. And I'm not sure on how I'm supposed to go about making it work the way I want it too.

Also, using Oracle.

Answer (score 4):

If you are learning SQL, you should learn to use explicit `join` syntax.  I think you are looking for the `having` clause; that is where conditions on aggregated amounts go:

```
SELECT s.SupplierName, SUM(p.Price)
FROM Suppliers s join
     Products p
     on s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID
GROUP BY s.SupplierName
HAVING SUM(p.Price) < 100;
```

I also added table aliases to your query (`s` and `p`).  These typically make a query easier to read, and they are needed for self joins.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT Suppliers.SupplierName, SUM(Products.Price) totalPrice
FROM Suppliers, Products
WHERE Suppliers.SupplierID = Products.SupplierID
GROUP BY Suppliers.SupplierName
HAVING totalPrice < 100;
```

Comment: You can't use the column alias in the `having` clause; it can only be used in `order by`, unless you use a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
WHERE Suppliers.SupplierID = Products.SupplierID
GROUP BY Suppliers.SupplierName
HAVING SUM(Products.Price) < 100;
```